# How far away can you be to hear a dungeon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I was mining, I heard an eerie noise, which means there is a dungeon nearby. How far away can you be from a dungeon before it gets triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "sound" does not indicate a [dungeon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon). This is what is referred to as "[ambience](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience)".

> Ambient sounds can be played in any dimension, including the Nether and the End, and can be heard in both singleplayer and multiplayer. **Ambience can occur in a space of any size, but they seem much more likely to be heard in larger spaces that are completely filled with a light level lower than 8**, without any lighting from the sky. Ambience is more likely to play from the direction of darker spaces. The space does not need to be sealed off or hidden - ambience can be heard from a space that the player can actually see - nor does the player need to be underground to hear ambient sounds.

There are many different types of ambient sounds, each one applying to a different part of the world - above ground, underground, the Nether and the End; but none indicate anything particularly special about the surrounding area.